# I am trying to find an equivalent unicode for this symbol ¤. Could anyone let me know?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, unicode, ascii

I am trying to find an equivalent unicode char for the symbol ¤. Could anyone please let me know? I tried \u0207 and other things.

Comment: Did you try `"\u00A4"`?

Comment: Yes, this is what i tried and worked, based on worker_bee's info. Thanks alot to both of you.

Comment: HTML uses Unicode so by putting it on this page, you already have it. Java uses Unicode so by pasting it into your source code, you'd be using it. (In some cases, people do transcode their source files to non-Unicode encodings, but in every case, you have tell the Java compiler what's being used, so it can transcode it back to Unicode.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a unicode map. Using http://www.unicodemap.org you could search for any unicode and find its corresponding unicode binary representation.

Here's the information I got from the site

```
Character Information   Unicode Range      UnicodeBinary    UCS-2Binary
"¤" CURRENCY SIGN       Latin-1 Supplement  0x00A4           0xA400
```

Comment: Sure. Np. Mark this answer as solved so that others can benefit from this question. Thanks.

Comment: I think i cannot vote, it is not allowing me to do saying it needs 15 reputations to do it. So, can anyone please do on behalf of me.

Answer (score -1):

In decimal, 164

Got this using ord() in python.